# How does Backbone renew collection models when needed

Tags: javascript, jquery, backbone.js

I have a this collection

```
var Product = Backbone.Model.extend({
           urlRoot:'/api/products',
           idAttribute:'id'
        });
    var Products = Backbone.Collection.extend({
        model:Product,
        url : '/api/products/'
    });
```

I fetch Models from server

```
var products = new Products();
products.fetch();
```

At some moment i change data on server and want 'products' to have the new data (renew the collection). I tried something like this

```
products.reset()
products.fetch()
```

But after this products in empty. Help me plz

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It is possible that the server does not respond in time. The proper way to reset your data is

```
products.fetch({reset: true}).success(function(response){
  // update the view here if necessary
})
```

Answer (score 0):

It might be because you're checking the contents of `products` before the server has time to return with the data. Check if `products` is still empty on the `success` callback instead:

```
products.fetch({
    success: function() {
        console.log(products.toJSON()); //is it still empty here? 
    }
});
```